# Linear Algebra book for beginners

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

sorry, if this question is redundant, but I think my case is a bit different.
I'm using videos on Khan's Academy to self-study Linear Algebra.And I also bought **Linear Algebra And its Applications. By Gilbert Strang** for some exercises. I finished watching all the videos on Vector&Subspaces and try to solve some practice problems in the book but got stuck on problem no.1 ... I'm not sure if this is the case of videos being not sufficient to teach all the necessary materials or book being too hard for beginners. I looked up some other books for beginners and found **Introduction to Linear Algebra. By Gilbert Strang(Online)**. Is this a more suitable book for me? and does it prep you for a college course?

Comment: I think you might have an easier time with Introduction to Linear Algebra, which is sometimes used as a textbook for lower division undergrad linear algebra courses.

Comment: The question is: what are you trying to follow and understand? The videos? The book Linear Algebra...by Strang? What is your goal here?

Comment: I guess lin alge in general.. I'm just using two sources to understand the concepts which is my goal..

Comment: I suggest you the online version of a "A First Course in Linear Algebra"  by Robert A. Beezer. It is avaiable from http://linear.ups.edu/download.html and what it is really great is the possibility to use the (free) software "sage" for the examples.

Comment: The recommendations in the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192552/how-to-self-study-linear-algebra) include some resources for getting the hang of proofs, if that's something that's new to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prerequisites/Books for A First Course in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/prerequisites-books-for-a-first-course-in-linear-algebra)