# Best way to self-study Linear Algebra, rigorously

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a high school (year 1) student with a meaningful background in olympiads and proof based mathematics. I recently have completed the group theory section of Gallian, and a few chapters of Baby Rudin. I am not referring to any video lectures as most of the OCW content available is of applied math or just the "will use this XYZ branch of math in data science/AI/etc." type course, at least in analysis and algebra. I want a deep and rigorous introduction to linear algebra, I'm comfortable with basic vector algebra and matrices so I'm pretty sure I won't be bumped off in the start. I wanted suggestions for any video course (preferably) or book which would satisfy my needs.

Comment: For self-study linear algebra, a helpful post also is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192552/how-to-self-study-linear-algebra), too.

Comment: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/linear-algebra-notes/